# Create popup boxes for each row in mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have the following code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $links = $rows['links'];
  $linksArray = explode(',', $links);
  if ($links == ""){
    unset($linksArray);
  }
?>
//LINK TO ACTIVATE POPUP BOX
<a href="#popup1">
<div class="newsBox">
      <h2><?php echo $rows['title'] ?></h2>
      <h4>Posted @ <?php echo $rows['date'] ?></h4>
      <?php
      if (!empty($linksArray)){
        ?>
      <span><i>Links associated with this post:</i>
      <? } ?>
      <?php
      foreach($linksArray as $link) {
        ?><a href="<? echo $link ?>">Here</a></span>
        <?
    }
    ?>
    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
        <?php echo $rows['news'] ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
<br>
</a>
<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

For each row identified by my query, it links it to a popup box. However all the rows being outputted activate the same popup box. My question is how to create my popup box such that each row being outputted is linked to different popup boxes, if that makes sense. Such as the first row, when linked opens a popup box with that row's info. The next row after, when linked opens a popup box with that row's info, and so on. (I guess maybe like a dynamic popup box?)

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql_*()` functions any more, please see this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Yeah yeah I know that but I like `mysql_*()` hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a counter in your loop and where you have your `<a href="#popup1">` and `<div id="popup1" class="overlay">` add in the counter variable like `<a href="#popup<?php echo $x ?>">` and `<div id="popup<?php echo $x ?>" class="overlay">`

This would make your popup id unique.

Comment: Thank you this is an amazing solution, which works for me.